# AES Encryption and Decryption in C

Tags: android, iphone, aes, encryption

I am creating an application where I save some privacy documents.
I want to save those files as Encrypted format.

I searched in google for AES Encryption/Decryption alto in C language. Am not able to find standard algorithm implementing AES.

Can anyone suggest me AES Enc/Dec in C ?? please

I would like to use the same algorithm in both android and iPhone

Comment: Why you need this algorithm while it is already implemented for android and iphone langues.

Comment: Sorry. Same algorithm in both languages ?? Actually. I need to use same algorithm in both languages. As well as I need to implement in Server side too.

Comment: @Perseus The algorithm is language independent. So you just need to learn how to perform AES encryption on both platforms, [hence my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13836456/474189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what Android and iPhone have to do with this, especially given that you're looking for a C implemetnation, but....

There's ccrypt:
http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/

Here's a really small one:
http://www.literatecode.com/aes256

A reference implementation:
http://embeddedsw.net/Cipher_Reference_Home.html

Another:
http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/index.php

mcrypt:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/

Comment: Thanks. Am going through your links. Looking for best one

Answer (score 0):

AES is a standard algorithm, so there should be no need to seek a "common" implementation in C. Instead, you should learn how to perform AES encryption in both platforms. Provided you are consistent with your encryption mode and padding, you should be able to interoperate just fine.